# Google Cloud Functions HTTP unable to successfully POST content type application/octet-stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, blob, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to write a [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http) HTTP handler to upload audio files constructed as blobs to Google Cloud Storage from a webpage. Based on the documentation linked above I want the body of my `POST` request to be handled as a Node.js `Buffer` and I can achieve this with `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`. I'm sending the request from a webpage that has this xhr request:

```
// where `var blob` is a Blob of type "audio/wav"
// and size of > 0 generated from the
// WebAudioAPI

var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onloadend = function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: GOOGLE_CLOUD_FUNCTION_URL,
    data: this.result,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
    success: function(resp) {
    },
    error: function(err) {
    }
  });
};
fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

and my Google Cloud Functions module looks like this:

```
exports.upload = function(req, resp) {

  resp.header('Content-Type','application/json');
  resp.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.get('origin'));
  resp.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

  switch (req.method) {
     case 'POST':
       response.status(200).send({
         contentType: request.get('content-type'),
         body: request.body,
         rawBody: request.rawBody
       });
       break;
  }

};
```

The request header shows that that there is data being attached. But, the content-type is not set as `application/octet-stream'. In addition the response returns:

```
{
  body: {}
}
```

What is the JavaScript `type` of data to pass to an ajax body for the Google Cloud Functions HTTP handler accept the body as a `Buffer`?

- Blob, File, Typed Array, Array Buffer?

Comment: Is this still a problem?  Does it behave differently that the documentation suggests?  https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#parsing_http_requests

Comment: Haven't tried since the post. I'll try again this weekend and update my post.